# Power connector size for HP 15-d053cl TouchSmart Notebook PC?

Tags: laptop, power-supply

Does anyone know what the inner and outer dimensions of the DC connector on the HP power adapter for the [HP 15-d053cl TouchSmart Notebook PC](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-15-Notebook-PC-series/6627588/model/6898163/product-info) is? Also, the name of the connector type would help.

The adapter’s model numbers are [709985-004, 710412-001, and AD9043-022G2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EO0HR1W). I need to find a connector that will go from 4.75mm x 1.7mm (L01D) to whatever connector is used on that adapter. Well, actually, I have several other connectors that go from 4.75mm x 1.7mm to other sizes, which I could use in conjunction with the second adapter. One of them is a 4.75mm x 1.7mm to 5.5mm x 2.5mm, so a 5.5mm x 2.5mm to whatever the size of my power cord is would work. I just need to know what size that is.

Comment: I have an identical PSU for another model and that that power adaptor has a TINY inset pin in the middle that's probably impossible to measure without completely wrecking the power supply connector. What're you really trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

The generic name for the connector is "coaxial DC power connector" but the specific measurements might be hard to find. It's difficult to accurately measure the inner pin even with digital calipers and it's not something most manufactures publish. Your best bet are likely the companies that specialize in replacement laptop power supplies. There are also some "modular" replacement power supplies that come with a variety of connector tips but make sure they specifically list your series of laptop as many only work with older laptops.

Using a power supply with the wrong voltage or current rating could damage the laptop, the power supply, or both. That's why companies like HP often use different sized proprietary or semi-proprietary power connectors. That prevents someone from trying to use say a 45 watt power supply on a laptop that needs 65 watts even if both are the same 19.5 volts. It also prevents you from accidentally plugging a Dell adapter into your HP.

You don't say why you need the connector but you might not find a way to convert sizes as you describe. Entire AC adapters/chargers for your laptop can be purchased on Amazon for under $20. And if you *really* need just the connector you can always buy the cheapest entire power supply you can find (often on eBay from Asia) and just cut the cord off.

Comment: Was also going to suggest cutting the cord off an old supply.

Comment: tldr. This is a bad idea ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek But bad ideas build character!

Comment: As to what he's trying to do http://superuser.com/questions/884351/is-battery-mah-measured-per-cell indicates he's trying to build an outboard power pack.

Answer (score 0):

On [newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA2V91RW5057) it says:

> Connector: 4.5 x 3.0 mm

[This ebay listing](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Power-AC-Adapter-Charger-fr-HP-Pavilion-15-D052NR-15-D053CL-15-D053NR-Touchsmart-/121543949234) gives the same size, as do the rest of the results at https://www.google.com/search?q=15-d053cl+ac+adapter+mm.

All seem to agree on 4.5x3.0, 19.5V, 65W. Not sure the polarity but one of those sites may have it listed.